# Sockets client+server with await/async c# 5.0

Tags: c#, асинхронность, async-await

Уже долго пытаюсь найти хотя бы какой-то пример, но пока безуспешно, поэтому обращаюсь с просьбой к вам.

Проблема такова. Хочу написать простое асинхронное клиент-серверное приложение с банальной передачей байт. Удалось найти и реализовать 2 решения: колбэки и `await/async` базирующиеся на `tcplistener` и `networkStream`. Но это все не то. Пытаюсь написать базируясь на `Task`, `Sockets` и `async/await` без `tcplistener` и `networkStream`. Почитал некоторую литературу, но необходимого ответа/примера не нашел.

Знаю, что делается это базируясь на следующем:

```
public static Task ConnectAsync(this Socket socket, EndPoint remoteEP) {
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(socket.BeginConnect, socket.EndConnect, remoteEP, null);
}
```

но пока ничего не выходит. Даже сервер не могу "собрать" воедино. Прошу помощи.

*Обновление*

Удалось подключиться.А вот с передачей пока не получается.

```
private readonly Socket _server;
public ServerSocket(IPAddress ipAddress, int port) {
    _server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    _server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port));
    _server.Listen(20);
    Console.WriteLine("Wait connection");
    Accept();
}
private async void Accept() {
    for (;;) {
        var socket = await Task.Factory.FromAsync < Socket > (_server.BeginAccept, _server.EndAccept, true);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему вы не можете найти пример, понятно. Сокеты немного устарели, вместо них обычно берут `TcpClient`.

Answer (score 4):

Для начала, правильный путь — это именно `async`/`await`.

По поводу работы с сокетами, вот есть [хороший обзор](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html).

Итак, создаём серверный сокет:

```
public ServerSocket(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
{
    _server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    _server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port));
    _server.Listen(20);
}
```

Здесь мы создали сокет, но основная работа у нас не мгновенна, поэтому выносим её в метод `Run`.

```
Task<Socket> AcceptAsync()
{
    return Task<Socket>.Factory.FromAsync(
           _server.BeginAccept, _server.EndAccept, null);
}

public async Task Run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var client = await AcceptAsync();
        var clientServeTask = ServeClient(client);
        // что дальше делать с этим заданием - ваше дело
        // например, вы можете просто записать его в список
    }
}
```

`ConnectAsync` для сервера не нужен.

В `ServeClient` инстанциируеем объект, представляющий клиента:

```
async Task ServeClient(Socket client)
{
    using (var c = new Client(client))
        await c.RunAsync();
}
```

В объект `Client` лежит собственно логика вашего сервера.

```
byte[] greeting = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hi, I'm server ru.SO/2015");
public async Task RunAsync()
{
    await SendAsync(greeting);
    var result = await ReceiveAsync(20);
    // ...
}
```

(Возможно, вам захочется вернуть результат.)

Ну и вспомогательные процедуры:

```
Task<int> TrySendAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags flags)
{
    return Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(
        _clientSocket.BeginSend, _clientSocket.EndSend,
        buffer, offset, size, flags, null);
}

Task SendAsync(byte[] buffer)
{
    int sent = 0;
    int remaining = buffer.Length;
    while (remaining > 0)
    {
        var partSent = await TrySendAsync(data, sent, remaining, SocketFlags.None);
        sent += partSent;
        remaining -= partSent;
    }
}
```

Не забудьте закрыть клиентский сокет в `Dispose`.

---

Да, наверняка вам захочется суметь оборвать работу сервера. Для этого вам стоит протянуть `CancellationToken`'ы через `Task`'и.

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать пример из другого вопроса - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516728/192004 .

Там создается 10 клиентов, сервер поочередно принимает их и отправляет ответы. Сервер работает в одном потоке (точнее, в одной Task), клиенты могут работать в разных потоках. Всё на async/await + куча советов.