# Socket client+server передается и принимается только 1 раз

Tags: c#, сокет, асинхронность, async-await

Я хочу постоянно передавать от сервера клиенту массив байт, но получается передать только 1 раз. Никак не пойму почему.

Сервер:

```
public ServerSocket(IPAddress ipAddress, int port) {
    _clients = new List <ClientModel> ();

    _server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    _server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port));
    _server.Listen(20);
    Accept();
}

private async void Accept() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var socket = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Socket>(_server.BeginAccept, _server.EndAccept, true);
        var newClient = new ClientModel {
            Id = _id++,
            ClientSocket = socket
        };
        _clients.Add(newClient);
        await Send(1, "hello " + i + "");
    }
}
public async Task Send(int id, String data) {
    var client = _clients.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.Id == id);
    if (client == null) return;

    var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    await Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(
        client.ClientSocket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, null, client.ClientSocket),
        client.ClientSocket.EndSend);
}
```

Клиент:

```
public ClientSocket() {
    _client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
}

public bool Connect(IPAddress ipAddress, int port) {
    _client.Connect(ipAddress, port);
    if (!_client.Connected) {
        return false;
    }
    Receive();
    return true;
}

private async void Receive() {
    var buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (;;) {
        try {
            var bytesRead = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(
                _client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, null, _client),
                _client.EndReceive);
            if (bytesRead <= 0) continue;

            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        } catch {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Учитывать надо, что одновременных клиентов может быть несколько. Проблема в том, что на 2ой итерации Сервер ждет на "BeginAccept/EndAccept", а клиент на "BeginReceive/EndReceive". Т.е получается, что клиент готов получать, а сервер не знает об этом. Подскажите как решить проблему.
Интересный факт: Если запустить сервер, затем клиент, то передастся массив 1 раз. Но если(ничего не закрываяя) открыть новый экземпляр клиента и выполнить его, то первый экземпляр пример 2ой раз массив. Если 2ой экземпляр клиента выполнить ещё раз, то первый примет 3ий массив. И так далее

Answer (score 1):

Тут много ошибок и недочетов:

1. Почему не работает ваш пример: `await Send(1, "hello " + i + "");` надо заменить на `await Send(i, "hello " + i + "");`, так как иначе мы будем отправлять только первому клиенту.
2. Вместе с await в данном случае надо ставить ConfigureAwait(false), чтобы ответ не приходит на UI. Если какой-то из вызывающих функций понадобиться переместиться на UI, она это сможет сделать.
3. catch без логгирования приведет к трудноуловимым ошибкам. Всегда надо хотя бы писать в лог.
4. Не надо использовать async void. В этом случае исключение в .Net 4.0 завалит приложение, а в .Net 4.5 оно просто потеряется.
5. Вместо `_id++` в данном случае лучше использовать `Interlocked.Increment`, так как приложение уже старается быть многопоточным.
6. Вместо использования класса Socket логичнее использовать TcpClient. Он имеет больше удобств.
7. Вместо Console.WriteLine лучше использовать await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync. Он асинхронный, пишет в правильный поток (т.к. надо разделять Out и Err, так как это разные pipeline).
8. В клиенте - вместо выхода по исключению лучше проверять, есть ли соединение, или уже нет.
9. И у сервера, и у клиентов должны быть Dispose методы
10. В текущем примере клиент никогда не останавливается. Я добавил остановку по переносу строки (`\n`)

Итого, чтобы просто запустить Ваш пример надо убрать ту самую единицу, см. первый пункт. Однако я переписал код, вдруг кому-нибудь понадобиться еще один пример клиент-серверного общения :-) В нем тоже есть недочеты, во благо упрощения кода, однако их поменьше.

```
internal static class MainClass
{
    private const int Port = 9635;

    public static void Main()
    {
        AsyncMain().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task AsyncMain()
    {
        using (var server = new ServerSocket(IPAddress.Loopback, Port))
        {
            var serverTask = server.Start();

            var clients = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).Select(_ => new ClientSocket()).ToArray();

            var connectionTasks = clients.Select(c => c.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, Port)).ToArray();

            await Task.WhenAll(connectionTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

            Array.ForEach(clients, c => c.Dispose());

            await serverTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


internal sealed class ClientModel
{
    public ClientModel(int id, Socket clientSocket)
    {
        // use nuget package 'CheckContracts'
        Validate.ArgumentGreaterOrEqualThanZero(id, nameof(id));
        Validate.ArgumentIsNotNull(clientSocket, nameof(clientSocket));

        Id = id;
        ClientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    public Socket ClientSocket { get; }
}

internal sealed class ServerSocket : IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<ClientModel> _clients;
    private readonly Socket _server;
    private int _id;

    public ServerSocket(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
    {
        _clients = new List<ClientModel>();

        _server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port));
        _server.Listen(20);
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var socket = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(_server.BeginAccept, _server.EndAccept, true).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var newClient = new ClientModel(Interlocked.Increment(ref _id), socket);

            _clients.Add(newClient);

            await SendAsync(newClient.Id, "hello " + newClient.Id + "\n").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(int id, string data)
    {
        var client = _clients.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.Id == id);

        Validate.IsNotNull(client, $"Unable to find client with id {id}");

        var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            client.ClientSocket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, null, client.ClientSocket),
            client.ClientSocket.EndSend).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_server, null))
        {
            _server.Dispose();
        }

        if (!ReferenceEquals(_clients, null))
        {
            foreach (var clientModel in _clients)
            {
                clientModel.ClientSocket.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}

internal sealed class ClientSocket : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Socket _client;

    public ClientSocket()
    {
        _client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
    {
        _client.Connect(ipAddress, port);
        if (!_client.Connected)
        {
            return false;
        }
        await ReceiveAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return true;
    }

    private async Task ReceiveAsync()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        for (;;)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_client.Connected)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var bytesRead = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                    _client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, null, _client),
                    _client.EndReceive).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (bytesRead <= 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (message.EndsWith("\n"))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_client, null))
        {
            _client.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, но на мой вкус `Array.ForEach(clients, c => c.Dispose());` читается намного хуже, чем `foreach (var c in clients) c.Dispose();`

Comment: Да, возможно. Здесь я бы советовал вообще использовать CompositeDisposable (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.compositedisposable(v=vs.103).aspx), однако тащить большое число зависимостей в ответ было бы не самой хорошей идеей.

Comment: Ого, не знал насчёт `CompositeDisposable`, беру на вооружение. Спасибо!