# Как разделить сокет на потоки?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, сервер, сокет, udp

Скажите, пожалуйста, как разделить UDP сокет на потоки, чтобы сервер мог одновременно принимать данные с десятерых клиентов на одном порту?

**UPD** :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD2** :

**Клиент** :

```
    // Конструктор клиента
    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(11001);
    udpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 11000);
    repeat:
    // Тут мы отправляем "типа" данные
    byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Привет :D");
    for (int i = 0; i < new Random().Next(100); i++)
    {
        udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
    }
    //Это я не знаю для чего, но без него программа не работает )
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    // А это мы получаем сообщение от клиента (Ну если условно, то сервера)
    Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
    string returnData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBytes);
    if (returnData == "Давай по новой")
    {
        goto repeat;
    }
    // Разрываем соединение.
    udpClient.Close();
```

**Сервер** :

```
async void RegisterTask(Task task)
{
    try
    {
        activeTasks.Add(task);
        await task;
    }
    finally
    {
        activeTasks.Remove(task);
    }
}
const int listenPort = 11000;
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var result = await listener.ReceiveAsync();
        Console.WriteLine($"Received from {result.RemoteEndPoint} {result.Buffer.Length} bytes");
        string returnData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Buffer);
        // если ваша обработка длительная, то стартуйте Task, обрабатывающий данные, здесь
        Task processTask = Process(result);
        RegisterTask(processTask);
    }
}

private Task Process(UdpReceiveResult result)
{
    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    Byte[] receiveBytes = listener.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
    string returnData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBytes);
    listener.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Давай по новой"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Давай по новой").Length);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: [Это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418010/10105)? Причём потоки не нужны, нужен async/await.

Comment: Окей. А почему тогда не `UdpClient`? UDP, если я не ошибаюсь, не требует соединения, поэтому разницы между клиентом и сервером по сути нет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, к нему ж приходит `RemoteEndPoint`, по нему и различать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: У меня в коде он выдаётся на консоль

Comment: не надо вставлять большие картинки - их сложно разглядывать и по ним не работает поиск.

Comment: Ну так просто видно в чём ошибка, если просто вставлять как код, то по любому будет "где ошибка?" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Обновление**: подправил код, чтобы он больше подходил к вашему случаю.

```
const int listenPort = 11000;

using (UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort))
{
    while (true) 
    {
        var result = await listener.ReceiveAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Received from {result.RemoteEndPoint} {result.Buffer.Length} bytes");
        // если ваша обработка длительная, то стартуйте Task, обрабатывающий данные, здесь
        Task processTask = Process(result);
    }
}

async Task Process(UdpReceiveResult result)
{
    var endpoint = result.RemoteEndPoint;
    byte[] message = result.Buffer;

    using (var sender = new UdpClient())
    {
        sender.Connect(endpoint.Address, destinationPort);
        var backMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Давай по новой");
        await sender.SendAsync(backMessage, backMessage.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39007/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-----).